# Extract data from OLE field in MS Access database

Tags: ms-access, ole

I have an MS Access mdb file that has a table with data in an OLE Object field.  When viewing the data it says 'Long binary data' in this field.  There is an additional column in this table that specifies what the OLE field contains - this says either 'Adobe Acrobat Document' or 'Microsoft Word Document'.  When viewing the table via a form the contents of the OLE field will neither display the contents or an icon using a bound object frame.

I have tried several methods for exporting this data but neither Word nor Adobe recognise the file when I try to open a document.  Adobe does not recognise the format and Word asks me to specify the encoding - I have tried the obvious from the list of encoding options but none make the document readable.

I have tried the following from a command button on a form, where the record source is the table with the OLE field.  Have tried these specifying the file name as .doc, .docx or .pdf where appropriate for that row of data.  I have tried this using Access from Office 365 back to 2007 and converting the mdb to accdb format.  All will create a document but I cannot read the contents.

Method 1

```
Dim mystream As New ADODB.Stream
Dim MyPath As String

MyPath = "C:\My path\My file name.doc"
mystream.Type = adTypeBinary
mystream.Open
mystream.Write Me!Documents 'reference to the control on my form
mystream.SaveToFile MyPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
mystream.Close
```

Method 2

```
Dim data() As Byte

data = Me!Documents
Open "C:\My path\My file name.doc" For Binary Access Write As #1
Put #1, , data
Close #1
```

Method 3

```
Dim sConn As String
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRs As New ADODB.Recordset

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=full path and file name of accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=********"

oConn.Open sConn
oRs.Open "SELECT tableName.FieldName FROM tableName WHERE (((tableName.id)=1))", oConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
LoadFileFromDB "full path and file name", oRs, "OLEfieldName"
oRs.Close
```

The LoadFileFromDB function is then:

```
Public Function LoadFileFromDB(FileName As String, RS As Object, FieldName As String) As Boolean
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim lFileLength As Long
Dim abBytes() As Byte
Dim iCtr As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If Not TypeOf RS Is ADODB.Recordset Then Exit Function

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open FileName For Binary As #iFileNum
lFileLength = LenB(RS(FieldName))

abBytes = RS(FieldName).GetChunk(lFileLength)
Put #iFileNum, , abBytes()
Close #iFileNum
LoadFileFromDB = True

ErrorHandler:
End Function
```

The front end for this Access mdb was not Access itself and I do not know what it was or how the data was inserted into the OLE field.  My client just needs to get it out if possible.  Am I doing something obviously stupid in the above samples or do I stand no chance of reading this data if I don't know how it got in there?  Thanks.

When opening one of the files in Word using text recovery this is what I am seeing.

````
Root Entry
Root Entry
Contents
Contents
CStorageItem
Root Entry
Root Entry
CompObj
CompObj
CONTENTS
CONTENTS
Acrobat Document
AcroExch.Document.DC
%PDF-1.7
%âãÏ
92 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 115075/O 94/E 109672/N 1/T 114766/H [ 493 178]>>
endobj
               

108 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<3643DDDCA0096D49B94B26A8F87F6F9F><D6948AE94979C841AEE3A5089F59C2D7>]/Index[92 33]/Info 91 0 R/Length 87/Prev 114767/Root 93 0 R/Size 125/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream

hÞbbd`
2

endstream
endobj
startxref

0

%%EOF

        

124 0 obj
<</C 92/Filter/FlateDecode/I 114/Length 92/S 38>>stream

hÞb``àc``ªg```\iÎ€

0

endstream
endobj
93 0 obj
<</Lang(en-GB)/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 2 0 R/Pages 90 0 R/StructTreeRoot 6 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences 109 0 R>>
endobj
````

Comment: I don't know how to view the headers.  How do I go about that?

Comment: Have created a few of the supposed pdf and word docs - when viewed in hex editor at address 00000000 they all have the entry that you specify above for a doc.

Comment: I did two of the rows specified as Word docs and they came out at 474 KB and 34 KB.  I did several of the rows specified as Acrobat files and they came out at 38, 55, 119, 192, 926, 2048 and 2439 KB.

Comment: Yes a single page could be expected as it could have been e.g. a reference for a job for someone.  Opened a file I had given the doc extension in WordPad and amongst all the 'garbage' did read [Content_Types].xml - so changed the file extension to .xml but it was still 'garbage' when I re-opened in WordPad.

Comment: Anything from 2008 to a couple of months ago

Comment: I don't understand your question 'is there some interference'.  I have now been able to read some of the documents from the later rows in the database that were specified as Word documents by changing their extension to docx.  Have changed a file I created with pdf extension to docx and it cannot read the file in Word - however by opening it with text recovery in Word I do get some sensible content at the start telling me this is an Acrobat file.  Guess I need to read your linked reference and this will give me an alternate way to extract the data - many thanks.

Comment: Have edited above question to show the start of one of the supposed pdf files when given docx extension and opened using text recovery in Word

Comment: I don't know how the files were originally saved into the database

Comment: Review http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm and https://medium.com/@haggenso/export-ole-fields-in-microsoft-access-c67d535c958d

Comment: Thanks will check those out

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, have come to the conclusion that this data must have been encrypted when stored as none of the suggested solutions have been able to extract the data in a readable format.